# Can't attach a ruleset for imuxsock in rsyslog

Tags: configuration, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I use **rsyslog 8.23** together with *systemd-journald* so I use the following configuration in rsyslog.conf (relevant portions of it) and it works this way with no problem - I can see all messages in *my-debug.log*:

```
module(load="imuxsock"
       SysSock.Use="on"
       SysSock.Name="/run/systemd/journal/syslog"
      )

module(load="builtin:omfile"
       Template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat"
       FileOwner="root"
       FileGroup="adm"
       dirOwner="root"
       dirGroup="adm"
       FileCreateMode="0640"
       DirCreateMode="0755"
      )


### Global Directives ###

global(workDirectory="/var/spool/rsyslog"
       umask="0022"
       preserveFQDN="on"
       localHostname="node1"
       AbortOnUncleanConfig="on"
       Shutdown.enable.ctlc = "on"
      )

# Direct all auth* log messages to local file
if ($syslogfacility-text == "auth" or $syslogfacility-text == "authpriv") then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/auth.log")
}

# Just for debug purposes only:
action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/my-debug.log")
```

But if I attach a **ruleset to imuxsock** - I have no messages in target log file (*/var/log/my-debug.log*):

```
module(load="imuxsock"
       SysSock.Use="on"
       SysSock.Name="/run/systemd/journal/syslog"
      )

module(load="builtin:omfile"
       Template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat"
       FileOwner="root"
       FileGroup="adm"
       dirOwner="root"
       dirGroup="adm"
       FileCreateMode="0640"
       DirCreateMode="0755"
      )


### Global Directives ###

global(workDirectory="/var/spool/rsyslog"
       umask="0022"
       preserveFQDN="on"
       localHostname="node1"
       AbortOnUncleanConfig="on"
       Shutdown.enable.ctlc = "on"
      )

# Direct all auth* log messages to local file
if ($syslogfacility-text == "auth" or $syslogfacility-text == "authpriv") then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/auth.log")
}

### ALL CHANGES HERE ###
input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/run/systemd/journal/syslog" ruleset="MyRuleset1")

ruleset(name="MyRuleset1") {
  action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/my-debug.log")
}
```

At first, I don't fully understand why does rsyslog make me put *'socket'* directive in *'input'* statement once more as I have already one in module declaration& What is *'SysSock.Name'* in module declaration then for?
And what is wrong with my second configuration - I have no clue. I think I followed a documentation strictly enough.
I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's important to know that in rsyslog, the order of the directives in the configuration matters (See: [Rsyslog Basic Structure](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/basic_structure.html#processing-order)):

> "Directives are processed from the top of rsyslog.conf to the bottom. Order matters. For example, if you stop processing of a message, obviously all statements after the stop statement are never evaluated."

The issue seems to be due to the structure of your configuration. So, simply swapping your `ruleset` and `input` should fix your problem.

```
### ALL CHANGES HERE ###
ruleset(name="MyRuleset1") {
  action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/my-debug.log")
}

input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/run/systemd/journal/syslog" ruleset="MyRuleset1")
```

---

Regarding your question about the socket configuration:

When setting `SysSock.Name` in the `imuxsock` module, it sets a global listener for syslog messages on that socket. This is a "catch-all" setup, which means any syslog message sent to this socket is processed by rsyslog following the global rules.

```
module(load="imuxsock"
       SysSock.Use="on"
       SysSock.Name="/run/systemd/journal/syslog"
      )

action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/my-debug.log")
```

However, you have to specify the socket again in the input statement if you use a ruleset, as you're essentially telling rsyslog to handle messages from this socket in a special way, separate from the global rules. Rsyslog treats inputs with an attached ruleset as separate streams of logs. When using the `input` statement, you have to specify the socket again, as you're creating a new, distinct path for these messages, even though the physical socket in your case is the same.

```
input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/run/systemd/journal/syslog" ruleset="MyRuleset1")
```

This means, with your current configuration, you can e.g. remove `SysSock.Name` from the global directive, or you can remove the `input` statement and define a global rule, which achieves the same result.

Comment: Thanks, it really worked as planned when I swapped ruleset and input. I never knew it played any role, but it as it is.